# MongoDB: $unwind before $group or after $group?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection of items that have many subitems and arrays. On page load I want to show first item with it's first subitems and other items with only their names displayed.

To sort subitems I use $unwind. Should I $unwind at the beginning of the query or after I have grouped the items

Performance wise, which should I prefer? :

```
const searchQuery = collection.aggregate([
    {"$group":{
        "_id":0,
        "first_element":{"$first":{"projects":"$projects"}},
    }},
    {$unwind: "$first_element.projects"},
    {"$sort":{
        "first_element.projects.project.date_modified":-1
    }},
]);
```

or this

```
const searchQuery = collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$first_element.projects"},
    {"$sort":{
        "first_element.projects.project.date_modified":-1
    }},
    {"$group":{
        "_id":0,
        "first_element":{"$first":{"projects":"$projects"}},
    }},
]);
```